# How Do I Count Number of Males and Females based on their month of birth in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a table with

```
NAME        GENDER      DOB         
swarna      Female      12-06-1991  
dayakar     male        12-06-1984  
monish      Male        01-06-1994  
er          Female      16-03-1995  
sd          Male        19-08-2005
```

i want to display bar chart with above info like 
In month wise how many females and males are there
[1 like this i want output]

for i have written code as follows in asp.net mvc

var data1 = db.Student.GroupBy(c => new { m = c.Gender }).Select(c => new BarChartViewmodel2
                {
                }).ToList();
pls guide me
thank you

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: select count(*) from table_name group by month(dob), gender;

Comment: i doing it in asp.net mvc .pls explain me in that

Comment: Can you show your asp.net code you already have? How should the result look?

Answer (score 1):

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', 'Male', 'Female'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400],
          ['2015', 1170, 460],
          ['2016', 660, 1120],
          ['2017', 1030, 540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Birth Count',
            subtitle: 'Birth Count',
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

```
DECLARE @Dobs TABLE(
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Gender VARCHAR(10),
    DateOfBirth DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Dobs(Name, Gender, DateOfBirth)
VALUES ('swarna', 'Female', '1991-06-12'),
('dayakar', 'male', '1984-06-12'),
('monish', 'Male', '1994-06-01'),
('newmen', 'Male', '1994-06-01'),
('er', 'Female', '1995-03-16'),
('sd', 'Male', '2005-08-19')

SELECT MonthValue, MonthName, SUM(MaleCount) AS MaleCount, SUM(FemaleCount) AS FemaleCount
FROM(
    SELECT Gender
        , MONTH(DateOfBirth) as MonthValue
        , DateName(mm,DATEADD(mm, MONTH(DateOfBirth) - 1,0)) MonthName
        , (CASE WHEN Gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MaleCount
        , (CASE WHEN Gender = 'FeMale' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FemaleCount
    FROM @Dobs
) as tbl
GROUP BY MonthValue, MonthName
```

This is MSSQL.

In MySQL, something like

```
SELECT MonthName, SUM(MaleCount) AS MaleCount, SUM(FemaleCount) AS FemaleCount
FROM(
    SELECT Gender
        , MONTHNAME(DateOfBirth) AS  MonthName
        , (CASE WHEN Gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MaleCount
        , (CASE WHEN Gender = 'FeMale' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FemaleCount
    FROM @Dobs
) as tbl
GROUP BY MonthName
```

The output will be like:

```
MonthName   MaleCount   FemaleCount
-------------------------------------------
August  1   0
June    0   1
June    3   0
March   0   1
```

So you will get the Birth Counts of Male & Female for all available months from your query itself. You need to set this to your Model and use as indented.

Comment: please explain in asp.net mvc

Comment: You can use 'Creating Material column charts' of Google Charts 'https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart' to attain the bar chart functionality

Comment: You need to change the value of 'data ' specified in drawChart() method, with your new value that you have obtained from the query. Either by ajax, Or with your stringyfied model and json manupilation over it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
select name, COUNT(*)as tot, 
  COUNT(case when details.gender='male' then 1 end) as male,
  COUNT(case when details.gender='female' then 1 end) as female 
  from YourTable where DOB='Date'
```